# Aligned vs Align spacing

Tags: align

I realized that using `aligned` results in unequal vertical spacing compared to `align`.

Code:

```
%\documentclass[12 pt,handout,notheorems]{beamer}
\documentclass[12 pt,handout,notheorems, serif]{beamer}
%\documentclass[12 pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[a4paper,landscape]
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts} %To get the accents aligned correctly, albeit in Computer Modern Roman
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mleftright}
\renewcommand{\left}{\mleft}
\renewcommand{\right}{\mright}
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        \begin{aligned}
            \dot{\lambda}_1^*\left(t\right) &= 0,\\
            \dot{\lambda}_2^*\left(t\right) &= -\lambda_1^*\left(t\right),
        \end{aligned}
        \quad \rightarrow \quad 
        \begin{aligned}
            \lambda_1^*\left(t\right) &= c_1.\\
            \lambda_2^*\left(t\right) &= -c_1t + c_2.
        \end{aligned}
    \end{equation}
    \begin{align}
        \dot{\lambda}_1^*\left(t\right) &= 0 & \lambda_1^*\left(t\right) &= c_1\\
        \dot{\lambda}_2^*\left(t\right) &= -\lambda_2^*\left(t\right) & \lambda_2^*\left(t\right) &= -c_1t + c_2
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For the `aligned` environment, is there a way to get the vertical spacing in the right group equal to that in the left group, like the `align` environment? In the right group, the equations are vertically closer than those in the first group.

Comment: the spacing rules are the same but the dot accent is forcing a bigger spacing so you could use \ phantom \dot\lambda, or globally increase the row spacing so that fits. (unrelated but don't use `\left \right` with `(t)` )

Comment: Off-topic: Instead of `\usepackage{mleftright} \renewcommand{\left}{\mleft} \renewcommand{\right}{\mright}`, please write `\usepackage{mleftright} \mleftright`. And, do please follow David Carlisle's advice to write `(t)` instead of `\mleft(t\mright)`.

Comment: @Mico, while David Carlisle's advice sounds reasonable, I like to use delimiters because it helps me not miss out on other parts delimiters.

Comment: @Superman - Are you at least willing to replace `\renewcommand{\left}{\mleft} \renewcommand{\right}{\mright}` with `\mleftright`?

Comment: Don't you mean `\usepackage{mleftright}` then `\mleft(...\mright)`? Sorry I am not sure what saying `\mleftright` does after the `\usepackage` command.

Comment: @Superman - No! In my earlier comment, I suggested you replace `\renewcommand{\left}{\mleft} \renewcommand{\right}{\mright}` in the preamble with just `\mleftright`. That's still my recommendation. Do you maybe have a philopophical objection to using the `\mleftright` macro as well?

Comment: Ok, then what does `\mleftright` by itself do?

Comment: @Superman - From the package's user guide: "Macro `\mleftright` redefines `\left` as `\mleft` and `\right` as `\mright`." `\mleftright` contains 10 characters; `\renewcommand{\left}{\mleft}\renewcommand{\right}{\mright}` contains 58 characters. I'm starting to get the impression that you like clutter not only in the  body of the document (by using lots of unneeded `\left` and `\right` directives) but in the preamble as well...

Comment: @Mico, sorry, but that sounds like a more concise way of doing so! I will keep that in mind! Thank you for letting me know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either equalize the rows with phantoms or lower the arrow.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,handout,notheorems, serif]{beamer}
%\documentclass[12 pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[a4paper,landscape]
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts} %To get the accents aligned correctly, albeit in Computer Modern Roman
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\lowerto}[1]{\raisebox{-#1}[0pt][0pt]{$\to$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    \dot{\lambda}_1^*(t) &= 0,\\
    \dot{\lambda}_2^*(t) &= -\lambda_1^*(t),
  \end{aligned}
  \quad \rightarrow \quad 
  \begin{aligned}
    \vphantom{\dot{\lambda}}\lambda_1^*(t) &= c_1.\\
    \vphantom{\dot{\lambda}}\lambda_2^*(t) &= -c_1t + c_2.
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    \dot{\lambda}_1^*(t) &= 0,               & \lowerto{2ex} && \lambda_1^*(t) &= c_1.\\
    \dot{\lambda}_2^*(t) &= -\lambda_1^*(t), &               && \lambda_2^*(t) &= -c_1t + c_2.
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Both require visual judgment, but it's essentially unavoidable.

Don't use `\left` and `\right` that way: you add useless bits of code for no gain.

[image]

Comment: +1 for "Don't use `\left` and `\right` that way." :-)